# Finding Some Mathematica Packages for Version 6

Tags: packages, version-6

For some reasons, I have to use Mathematica 6 version and I need the following packages:

ErrorBarPlots`

Histograms`

PlotLegends`

Can anybody help me to find these packages? It is really important for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are included in v6, except for ErrorBarPlots. https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/guide/StandardExtraPackages.html You just need to load them, as shown in the documentation I linked. Anything taken from a later version (ErrorBarPlots) will very likely not work with earlier versions.

Comment: As far as I know, all the mathematica add-on packages can be downloaded from the website. But I couldn’t find the relating packages. And sure they can be shared. I don’t have a running version with these on it at school.

Comment: As I said, they are part of version 6. If you have Mathematica 6 (and not some other version), then Histograms and PlotLegends are part of it. You do not have to download it.

Comment: `ErrorListPlot[]` and `Histogram[]` in version six should be in the package [``Graphics`Graphics`​``](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6808/), while the legending functionality is in [``Graphics`Legend`​``](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6818/).